# Striping down for java/swing only thin client

Tags: performance, raspbian-wheezy, java, lxde

Very important note: This same question is also asked at the raspberry pi forums. I guarantee to copy answers from here to there with correct credentials.

Hello everyone

I am currently developing a java project that is going to be a network of raspberry pi powered sensor stations. For this purpose I want to have my debian wheezy to bare minimum.

Although I am a regular linux user, I really don't know about all my options here. Is LXDE good or is there even lighter alternative (fluxbox?)? Which services could be closed? Is it possible to start an x enviroment with only one active window and no other programs ? In general if I want to run Java/Swing on bare metal Raspberry pi. Is there any path to be taken?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you having one raspberry pi with a lot of sensors connected or a lot of raspberry pi´s which are connected?

Answer (score 1):

if your sensor stations are headless (= no monitor attached), you may easily disable "boot to desktop" by running `raspi-config` and choosing the appropriate option.

then you might reconfigure memory, to give 16MB to the GPU and the rest to the system.

i would not recommend to go anywhere beyond that, your system would be lean and mean enough, with the minimum of the processes running.

Comment: I think he needs his Java app to run in an isolated X window. Like kiosk mode in Chrome or Windows.